# What does "corresponding author" mean?

Tags: authorship, latex

What is the Corresponding author about in the list of authors of a Journal or Conference paper? As fas as I read, it is the person who confirms results or whom actually is the intellectual mind of the idea behind the published work. Can it be more than 1 author in some cases then?